# Jmeter as a proxy for a tool

Tags: proxy, jmeter

If I use performance metric module of JMeter for calculating network I/O usage and in parallel start a tool and JMeter to generate traffic .  Does the network I/O usage that JMeter show me, calculate that tool traffic?

If JMeter does not calculate the tool traffic, please give me solution about proxy JMeter for a tool that generate traffic. in fact  I want  JMeter to  become as a proxy for a tool. In other words, I want to direct a tool traffic to JMeter. How can I do this?

My tool is "OWASP HTTP DOS TOOL".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JMeter can act as a proxy for any tool given:

- The tool is using HTTP or HTTPS protocols
- The tool has proxy configuration or respects system-wide proxy settings

Setting up [JMeter's HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) is fairly easy and simple, the fastest way to prepare JMeter's proxy is using [JMeter Templates](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-save-%E2%80%98loads%E2%80%99-time-using-jmeters-template-feature) feature

1. From JMeter's main menu choose `File -> Templates -> Recording` and click "Create" button

   [image: JMeter recording configuration from template]
2. Expand `Workbench -> HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder` and click `Start` button

   [image: JMeter start proxy]
3. Configure your tool to use JMeter as a proxy, mind that default JMeter's proxy port is `8888`